# "Select All" the goes beyond the viewable screen

Tags: interface, ux-designer, multi-selection, payment

I am working on an invoice board to make bulk payments. When a user "selects all" should it select only the viewable cells or all cells?

Another question is should the web page have unlimited scrolling or pagination with the ability to select all cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good option is to give the user the choice whether to select all visible items or all items. This is an example what Gmail does when I use the select all option:

[image]

It selects everything on the page but gives me the choice to do a global select.